# 8085 microprocessor connection of CPU data bus with RAM data bus

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu, cpu-cache

What would happen if the CPU data-bus bit 2 is connected to the RAM data-bit 5 and CPU data-bus
bit 5 is connected to RAM data bit 2? Assume the rest of the connections are all right – explain.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69452870/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/144416/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1):

Not much. Bits 2 and 5 will get swapped over when the CPU reads memory but also when it writes memory, so it cancels out. It will only make a difference if some other hardware device is also accessing the RAM and *not* swapping over those bits.